# Construct a Map for each Enum type in Kotlin

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, enums

I have an Enum class like

```
enum class Definition(
    val definitionName: String,
    val parameters: Map<String, String>,
    val definitionPath: String = "com/1.0"
) {
    APPLE(
        "this-is-an-apple",
        mapOf("1" to "2")
    ),
    BANANA(
        "this-is-banana",
        mapOf("3" to "4")
    )
}
```

I would like to construct maps for each enum without specifying the keys and values, like for APPLE

```
mapOf("definition" to "this-is-an-apple",
      "parameters" to mapOf("1" to "2"),
      "definitionPath" to "com/1.0"
)
```

Comment: What is this intended for?  (For example, if your goal is to write it out as JSON, you'd be better off using a library to do that conversion.)

Comment: Hi, I'm storing some predefined values in this enum, and the values will be merged with some other dynamic ones into a map to be passed to downstream services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you want to map all values of the `enum` to a list of maps. You can use `values()` function to go through each item of `enum` and Kotlin Reflection API:

```
val maps: List<Map<String, Any>> = Definition.values().map { enumItem ->

    val pairList = mutableListOf<Pair<String, Any>>()

    Definition::class.declaredMemberProperties.forEach { property ->
        val value = property.apply { isAccessible = true }
                        .get(enumItem)
        value?.let { pairList.add(Pair(property.name, it)) }
    }

    mapOf(*pairList.toTypedArray())
}
```

To use reflection api add next line to the app's **build.gradle** file dependencies:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey, what I really want to achieve is how to not specifically tell what are the keys and values. Like I am able to use gson to transform a data class into a map, I wonder how to do the similar thing with enum

Comment: @YIWENGONG I think without reflection we can't do it. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!